# Altorouter multilingual routing

Tags: routes, multilingual, altorouter

Is it possible to use Altorouter to create a multilingual routing setup?
I'd want to send a variable with the target file (so that it displays different contents when viewed), e.g. -

```
$router->map('GET','/th/work/sample', 'work/sample.php', 'sample', 'th');
```

But that fifth parameter isn't available. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pattern-matching in the URL to achieve this, if the your language URLs are regular enough.

According to the [documentation](http://altorouter.com/usage/mapping-routes.html), defining the route

```
$router->map('GET', '/[:lang]/work/sample', 'work/sample.php', 'sample')
```

will capture `'th'` in `$lang` when the `'/th/work/sample'` URL is hit. If you need more complex pattern matching, custom regexes can be also be specified.

Answer (score 2):

> `$router->map('GET','/th/work/sample', 'work/sample.php', 'sample', 'th');`
>
> > But that fifth parameter isn't available. Is there any workaround for this?

That is because the map function just does not support a fifth parameter.

`public function map($method, $route, $target, $name = null)`

[source code AltoRouter.php:map](https://github.com/dannyvankooten/AltoRouter/blob/master/AltoRouter.php#L101)

You can call `match` function passing in the original route if you can somehow intercept and get your code to work before router. The match function returns you a route name. But this means you create named routes for each language and then you will begin to appreciate the solution provided by @gbe

`$router->map('GET', '/[:lang]/work/sample', 'work/sample.php', 'sample')`